# Using @available get error unexpected ‘@‘ in program while compiling using command line

Tags: ant, ios11, command-line-tool

Recently I have used **@available** to check if the iOS version is 11 for certain condition calls. When I build using command line (using ant) I get an error as “error: unexpected ‘@‘ in program”

Before adding that I was able to make a build successfully. But now showing me this error.

**Note** : I am able to make a build using Xcode but not able to make build using command line

Comment: Found? Help me as I am suffering from the same issue